# What is the use of Background App Refresh?

Tags: ios, iphone

I never realised any advantage of having that feature turned on, nor turned off.

How can educate myself about what it does so that I can choose whether to turn it on or off either for the entire system or for specific applications?

Comment: Have a look at: [Understand multitasking and background activity on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070)

Comment: I would say that the most obvious app I have experienced with it is Mailbox. I used it before and after background refresh and the difference is quite remarkable. Mailbox supports push notifications so those are always the same, the difference is after the app is opened, everything is practically up-to-date.

Answer (score 6):

Some apps like Facebook keep getting new feed posts in the background when you are not using the app. This gives the impression when you launch the app that it is really fast and everything is already there and your main UI isn't filled with blank spots for image placeholders and things of that sort.

The biggest impact I've seen on it is that is uses a TON of cellular data when my wife checks her Facebook on lunch break, then it keeps refreshing for the next 4 hours until she gets home to wifi.

I try to turn off background app refresh for most apps. A good hypothetical use for it would be some app that tracks tour mileage and plots it on a map. You may be on a long trip and you don't need to be looking at a phone while driving, so this would be a good use for background app refresh so the app can continue to measure your distance even when you have your phone locked or are on the phone itself.

Comment: But most apps which can record your trip/track data in the background do not even appear on the Background App Refresh screen. So why would this be needed? You don't need to download anything from the internet to track location, so this shouldn't be necessary.  Core Location services should be enough for your hypothetical app?

Answer (score 2):

Background refresh and location services are two different things. Most navigation apps like Waze ***do not*** use background refresh to provide routing or directions. They use Core Location, which uses a combination of GPS and Wi-Fi to get your exact location, even in the background.

Waze ***does*** use Background Refresh, but who knows exactly what for, or how much this would hinder its functionality. Background Refresh will launch your app in the background, and give it a bit of time to perform some action.  How often this occurs is totally opaque to the user or developer. It's up to the operating system.

Comment: One use case for background refresh with Waze is when you're driving with navigation enabled, and then you have a call, which you accept.  If you don't have background refresh Waze will simply exit and you'll have to reopen it after the call.  If you do have background app refresh then Waze will be still running and continue to give voice directions even during the call itself (at least that's what Google Maps does).

Answer (score 0):

Background Refresh is a feature whose name describes exactly what it does.
It allows apps to automatically refresh their content in the background.
This means that whenever you open the app you'll always have new content.

For example: Waze is a navigating app that needs Background Refresh to constantly get your location and give you directions even if the app isn't open and is running in the background.
Turning it off would hinder apps from doing things like this.
I recommend you to go through the list and turn off ones that you don't think will need to refresh/get new content when the app is closed.
If you do this you might see an increase in battery life.

Comment: Are you absolutely **certain** that Background Refresh is used/required by Waze to get your location in the background? If so why? Apps certainly don't need Background App Refresh to get the location in the background. TomTom, Apple Maps, Google Maps all do NOT use background app refresh and they all work fine. Background app refresh is only used for downloading files (like news feeds or weather data) from the internet - it has no other purpose.

Comment: When I see comments like "XYZ is a feature whose name describes exactly what it does", I know it means this person's guess is as good as mine